# PyQt position in QGraphicsView is shifted

Tags: python, python-2.7, pyqt, pyqt4, chess

I'm trying to draw a chessboard with its pieces in PyQt. Therefore I'm using a QtGui.QMainWindow. In the QMainWindow I place a QtGui.QGridLayout and to the grid I add a QtGui.QGraphicsView as a central widget. The QGraphicsView should hold the chessboard with the 64 tiles and the pieces as QtGui.QGraphicsItem.

I implemented this but now I have a problem with the positioning. It seems like the position for everything is shifted or offset by a certain amount and it seems like this amount depends on the position of the QGraphicsItem. The tiles aren't next to each other, but there is space between them with the same size of a tile. And when I drag and drop a piece (I have overriden the funtions because I want to make some adjustments for moving the pieces: keep them on the board even when the mouse leaves the board, center the piece under the cursor even when it is grabbed at the corner) it seems like the distance that the piece is moving is doubled.

I made screenshots of my gui to illustrate the problems. In the second image, I started dragging in the upper left corner and marked the position of mouse and piece. The distance between the cursor and the piece is varying with the cursor-position.
https://i.stack.imgur.com/pAQuV.png
https://i.stack.imgur.com/09LvG.png

So here is the source code, please can you have a look and help me:

chessboard.py

```
import sys
from board import *

class MainWindow(QtGui.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super(MainWindow, self).__init__()
        self.initUI()


    def initUI(self):
        grid = QtGui.QGridLayout()
        grid.setColumnStretch(1,1)
        grid.setRowStretch(1,1)

        self.board = Board()
        grid.addWidget(self.board)

        mainWidget = QtGui.QWidget()
        mainWidget.setLayout(grid)
        self.setCentralWidget(mainWidget)

        self.setGeometry(200, 200, 800, 600)
        self.setWindowTitle('ChessBoard')
        self.show()

def main():
    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    m = MainWindow()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

board.py

```
from PyQt4 import QtGui, QtCore, QtSvg

SQHT = 60
WHITE, BLACK = COLORS = range(2)
LIGHT_COL = QtGui.QColor(220,225,235)
DARK_COL = QtGui.QColor(130,150,180)

class Board(QtGui.QGraphicsView):
    def __init__(self):
        super(Board, self).__init__(None)
        self.scene = QtGui.QGraphicsScene(self)
        self.setScene(self.scene)

        self.svg = '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?> <!-- Creator: CorelDRAW --> <svg    xmlns:dc="http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/"    xmlns:cc="http://web.resource.org/cc/"    xmlns:rdf="http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#"    xmlns:svg="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"    xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"    xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"    xmlns:sodipodi="http://sodipodi.sourceforge.net/DTD/sodipodi-0.dtd"    xmlns:inkscape="http://www.inkscape.org/namespaces/inkscape"    xml:space="preserve"    width="50mm"    height="50mm"    shape-rendering="geometricPrecision"    text-rendering="geometricPrecision"    image-rendering="optimizeQuality"    fill-rule="evenodd"    clip-rule="evenodd"    viewBox="0 0 50 50"    id="svg2"    sodipodi:version="0.32"    inkscape:version="0.45"    sodipodi:docname="bn.svg"    sodipodi:docbase="/home/fkling/2/v0.1.2reduced/PieceThemes/Merida"    inkscape:output_extension="org.inkscape.output.svg.inkscape"    sodipodi:modified="true"><metadata    id="metadata13"><rdf:RDF><cc:Work        rdf:about=""><dc:format>image/svg+xml</dc:format><dc:type          rdf:resource="http://purl.org/dc/dcmitype/StillImage" /></cc:Work></rdf:RDF></metadata><defs    id="defs11"><linearGradient      inkscape:collect="always"      id="linearGradient2165"><stop        style="stop-color:#ffffff;stop-opacity:1;"        offset="0"        id="stop2167" /><stop        style="stop-color:#ffffff;stop-opacity:0;"        offset="1"        id="stop2169" /></linearGradient><linearGradient      inkscape:collect="always"      xlink:href="#linearGradient2165"      id="linearGradient2171"      x1="21.253071"      y1="37.59214"      x2="77.641281"      y2="37.469292"      gradientUnits="userSpaceOnUse" /></defs><sodipodi:namedview    inkscape:window-height="625"    inkscape:window-width="944"    inkscape:pageshadow="2"    inkscape:pageopacity="0.0"    guidetolerance="10.0"    gridtolerance="10.0"    objecttolerance="10.0"    borderopacity="1.0"    bordercolor="#666666"    pagecolor="#ffffff"    id="base"    inkscape:zoom="2.2972888"    inkscape:cx="119.13229"    inkscape:cy="84.28695"    inkscape:window-x="259"    inkscape:window-y="109"    inkscape:current-layer="svg2"    showgrid="true" />  <g    id="Layer_x0020_1">   <metadata    id="CorelCorpID_0Corel-Layer" />   <path    fill="#1F1A17"    d="M26.178 9.3952c2.5993,0.1694 5.0038,0.8382 7.2221,2.0151 2.2098,1.1684 4.0979,2.6755 5.6557,4.5127 1.0922,1.287 2.1167,2.8448 3.0819,4.6652 0.9737,1.8118 1.7441,3.7422 2.3199,5.7742 0.6604,2.3707 1.0837,4.8514 1.253,7.4592 0.1778,2.5992 0.2625,5.0122 0.2625,7.2305l0 5.4017c0,0 -1.2869,0 -3.8608,0 -2.5654,0 -5.9013,0 -10.0076,0l-16.637 0c-0.1524,0 -0.2201,-0.4064 -0.2117,-1.2107 0.0085,-0.8128 0.0593,-1.4647 0.1609,-1.9643 0.0593,-0.3979 0.2201,-0.9567 0.4657,-1.6848 0.254,-0.7282 0.6604,-1.6087 1.2446,-2.6501 0.2624,-0.5334 0.889,-1.3039 1.8796,-2.3199 0.999,-1.016 2.1336,-2.2013 3.429,-3.539 0.745,-0.762 1.3208,-1.7188 1.7441,-2.8787 0.4233,-1.1515 0.6011,-2.2013 0.5334,-3.1496 -0.6096,0.4995 -1.2785,0.9059 -2.0066,1.2192 -3.5052,1.2531 -6.0452,3.0734 -7.6115,5.4525 -0.1186,0.1524 -0.4911,0.8213 -1.1176,2.0151 -0.3302,0.6265 -0.6181,1.0583 -0.8467,1.2869 -0.3133,0.3133 -0.7705,0.4911 -1.3631,0.525 -0.9229,0.0423 -1.6426,-0.398 -2.159,-1.3462 -0.6943,0.2032 -1.3124,0.2878 -1.8627,0.254 -0.9229,-0.3472 -1.5917,-0.7197 -2.0066,-1.1176 -0.8467,-0.8467 -1.3885,-1.6849 -1.651,-2.5316 -0.254,-0.8466 -0.381,-1.7526 -0.381,-2.7262 0,-1.3886 0.8551,-3.2258 2.5823,-5.5118 2.0151,-2.6247 3.0904,-4.6313 3.2174,-6.0029 0,-0.5927 0.0592,-1.2615 0.1778,-2.0066 0.1016,-0.5165 0.3048,-1.0075 0.618,-1.4901 0.2202,-0.3302 0.3641,-0.5588 0.4318,-0.6774 0.0762,-0.127 0.2117,-0.3132 0.4149,-0.5588 0.1439,-0.2032 0.2709,-0.3556 0.3725,-0.4572 0.0932,-0.11 0.2202,-0.254 0.3726,-0.4402 0.1778,-0.2117 0.4064,-0.4572 0.6942,-0.7451 -0.8805,-2.413 -1.2361,-4.9022 -1.0668,-7.4591 3.2851,1.1684 6.0537,3.0141 8.2804,5.5287 0.5504,-1.8711 1.6256,-3.3867 3.2258,-4.5381 1.3208,0.9228 2.3707,2.1505 3.1496,3.666z"    id="path6" />   <path    fill="white"    d="M 15.6878,17.7857 C 16.0519,17.5994 16.2297,17.5063 16.2297,17.5063 C 16.7292,17.3116 16.8816,16.9475 16.7038,16.4141 C 16.5091,15.923 16.1281,15.7537 15.5608,15.923 C 13.6135,16.6342 12.2673,17.9381 11.5222,19.8431 C 11.4037,20.385 11.5984,20.7575 12.1149,20.9607 C 12.6314,21.1216 12.9785,20.9438 13.1563,20.4104 C 13.2918,20.131 13.3849,19.9447 13.4526,19.8685 C 13.6389,20.0124 13.876,20.114 14.1723,20.1648 C 15.1798,20.3257 15.7725,19.8854 15.9334,18.8271 C 15.9842,18.463 15.8995,18.1159 15.6878,17.7857 L 15.6878,17.7857 z M 11.573,34.5497 C 11.6323,34.3973 11.7424,34.1772 11.8948,33.8808 C 12.1742,33.1866 12.3096,32.7717 12.3096,32.6362 C 12.2842,32.179 12.0387,31.942 11.59,31.942 C 11.2598,31.942 10.8788,32.4161 10.43,33.3559 C 10.3623,33.4914 10.2607,33.6099 10.1337,33.703 C 9.685,34.1687 9.7527,34.5582 10.3284,34.8714 L 10.3284,34.8714 C 10.8618,35.1847 11.2682,35.0831 11.573,34.5497 L 11.573,34.5497 z M 26.2034,25.3464 C 27.3634,23.8224 27.9306,22.1291 27.9137,20.2664 C 27.846,19.7161 27.5327,19.4452 26.9739,19.4452 C 26.2119,19.4452 25.9156,19.7246 26.0764,20.2834 C 26.1272,21.1978 26.0426,21.9513 25.8055,22.544 C 25.4245,23.4838 25.0012,24.1865 24.544,24.6522 C 24.29,25.1517 24.4424,25.5158 24.9927,25.7444 L 24.9927,25.7444 C 25.5176,25.9899 25.924,25.8629 26.2034,25.3464 L 26.2034,25.3464 z M 19.7264,13.2391 C 19.6502,12.6464 19.6672,12.003 19.7772,11.3087 C 18.7866,11.5034 17.8553,11.9691 16.9748,12.6972 C 16.4498,12.9766 16.3228,13.3661 16.6022,13.8656 C 16.8816,14.3736 17.2711,14.4583 17.7706,14.1112 C 18.1178,13.9249 18.4395,13.7556 18.7274,13.6032 C 19.0152,13.4423 19.3454,13.3238 19.7264,13.2391 L 19.7264,13.2391 z M 42.9759,44.6928 C 42.959,44.6928 42.9759,44.244 43.0182,43.3466 C 43.149425,40.239133 43.11367,37.125892 43.0944,34.0163 C 43.0775,31.8065 42.7812,29.6052 42.2054,27.4038 C 41.365664,24.093859 40.08136,20.919205 38.133,18.1074 C 35.498872,14.261975 31.31864,12.073755 26.8469,11.1309 C 26.973151,11.896697 26.87985,12.670913 26.9231,13.4423 C 28.5233,13.9842 30.0388,14.6615 31.4612,15.4743 C 35.702058,18.028667 37.875209,22.749659 38.6579,27.4038 C 39.929701,33.557961 39.110533,38.961296 39.4707,44.6928 L 42.9759,44.6928 L 42.9759,44.6928 z M 9.4394,30.1386 C 9.9136,29.7999 9.9644,29.4104 9.5834,28.9448 C 9.1854,28.5638 8.7536,28.5299 8.271,28.8432 C 7.2635,29.5036 6.7216,30.3756 6.6539,31.4509 C 6.6708,31.9928 7.001,32.2552 7.6276,32.2214 C 8.2202,32.1706 8.5081,31.8658 8.4912,31.2985 C 8.6266,30.7736 8.9399,30.3841 9.4394,30.1386 z "    id="path8"    style="fill-opacity:1.0;fill:url(#linearGradient2171)"    sodipodi:nodetypes="cccccccccccccccsccccccccscccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccc" />  </g> </svg>'
        self.pieces = []
        self.bRect = QtCore.QRectF(0,0,8*SQHT,8*SQHT)
        self.RANKS = 8
        self.FILES = 8

        self.setRenderHints(
            QtGui.QPainter.Antialiasing | QtGui.QPainter.TextAntialiasing | QtGui.QPainter.SmoothPixmapTransform)
        self.setVerticalScrollBarPolicy(QtCore.Qt.ScrollBarAlwaysOff)
        self.setHorizontalScrollBarPolicy(QtCore.Qt.ScrollBarAlwaysOff)
        self.setDragMode(self.NoDrag)
        self.setInteractive(True)
        self.setTransformationAnchor(self.NoAnchor)
        self.scene.setItemIndexMethod(self.scene.NoIndex)
        self.setMouseTracking(True)
        self.setAlignment(QtCore.Qt.AlignTop | QtCore.Qt.AlignLeft)


        self.drawBoard()

        self._drawPiece(0, 0, WHITE, self.svg)

        for piece in self.pieces:
            piece.setMovable(True)


    def isLight(self, row, col):
        return (row % 2) == (col % 2)

    def drawBoard(self):
        for col in range(self.FILES):
            for row in range(self.RANKS):
                BTile(self, row, col, LIGHT_COL if self.isLight(row, col) else DARK_COL)

    def _drawPiece(self, row, col, color, piece):
        BPiece(self, row, col, color, piece)

    def getBRect(self):
        return self.bRect


class BoardElement(QtGui.QGraphicsItem):
    #TODO make abstract - how can I do this and keep inheritance from QGraphicsItem?
    def __init__(self, board, row, col):
        super(BoardElement, self).__init__(None)
        self.board = board
        x, y = self._rowCol2Pos(row, col)
        self.setPos(x,y)
        board.scene.addItem(self)

    def _rowCol2Pos(self, row, col):
        x = col * SQHT
        y = row * SQHT
        return x, y

    def _updatePos(self, x, y):
        self.setPos(x,y)
        self.board.scene.update()

    def _getXYOnBoardCentered(self, mx, my):
        rect = self.board.getBRect()
        dh = int(SQHT/2)
        left = mx - dh
        right = mx + dh
        top = my - dh
        bottom = my + dh
        if left < rect.left():
            x = rect.left()
        elif right > rect.right():
            x = rect.right() - SQHT
        else:
            x = mx - dh
        if top < rect.top():
            y = rect.top()
        elif bottom > rect.bottom():
            y = rect.bottom() - SQHT
        else:
            y = my - dh
        return x,y

    def _getXYOnBoard(self, mx, my):
        rect = self.board.getBRect()
        dh = int(SQHT/2)
        left = mx - dh
        right = mx + dh
        top = my - dh
        bottom = my + dh
        if left < rect.left():
            x = rect.left()
        elif right > rect.right():
            x = rect.right() - SQHT
        else:
            x = mx
        if top < rect.top():
            y = rect.top()
        elif bottom > rect.bottom():
            y = rect.bottom() - SQHT
        else:
            y = my
        return x,y


class BTile(BoardElement):
    def __init__(self, board, row, col, sqColor):
        super(BTile, self).__init__(board, row, col)
        self.sqColor = sqColor
        x, y = self._rowCol2Pos(row, col)
        self.bRect = QtCore.QRectF(x, y, SQHT, SQHT)

    def boundingRect(self):
        return self.bRect

    def paint(self, painter, option, widget):
        painter.setPen(self.sqColor)
        painter.setBrush(self.sqColor)
        painter.drawRect(self.bRect)


class BPiece(BoardElement):
    def __init__(self, board, row, col, color, piece):
        super(BPiece, self).__init__(board, row, col)
        self.color = color
        self.piece = piece
        self.svg = piece
        self.pixmap = QtSvg.QSvgRenderer(QtCore.QByteArray(self.svg))
        self._updateBRect()
        self.movable = False
        self.setAcceptHoverEvents(True)
        self.setZValue(2)
        x, y = self._rowCol2Pos(row, col)
        self.setPos(x,y)
        board.pieces.append(self)

    def _updateBRect(self):
        self.bRect = QtCore.QRectF(self.pos().x(), self.pos().y(), SQHT, SQHT)

    def boundingRect(self):
        self._updateBRect()
        return self.bRect

    def paint(self, painter, option, widget):
        self._updateBRect()
        self.pixmap.render(painter, self.bRect)

    def setMovable(self, movable):
        self.movable = movable
        self.setFlag(QtGui.QGraphicsItem.ItemIsMovable, self.movable)

    def hoverMoveEvent(self, event):
        if self.movable:
            self.setCursor(QtCore.Qt.OpenHandCursor)
            self.setFocus()

    def mousePressEvent(self, event):
        QtGui.QGraphicsItem.mousePressEvent(self, event)
        self.setCursor(QtCore.Qt.ClosedHandCursor)
        self.setZValue(3)

    def mouseMoveEvent(self, event):
        pos = event.scenePos()
        x,y = self._getXYOnBoardCentered(pos.x(), pos.y())
        self._updatePos(x,y)

    def mouseReleaseEvent(self, event):
        self.setZValue(2)
        p = event.pos()
        bx,by = self._getXYOnBoard(p.x(), p.y())
        x = (bx // SQHT) * SQHT
        y = (by // SQHT) * SQHT
        self._updatePos(x,y)
```

Comment: I'm having a slightly similar issue but in a different way. My widgets - when moved - seem to shift the perspective of the GraphicsView widget outwards. As if it's trying to resize itself to keep all the widgets as close to the center as possible. Which is an insanely stupid feature. Trying to fix it. Looks like nobody wants to help out